TensorFlow.keras namespace not recognized by PyLance in Visual Studio Code
I'm encountering an issue with PyLance in Visual Studio Code where the tensorflow.keras namespace isn't being recognized, leading to incomplete IntelliSense and auto-completion. It appears that this problem stems from the lazy loading functionality (_KerasLazyLoader) utilized by TensorFlow to defer loading unnecessary packages until they are needed.
I've searched through existing questions on this topic, but the most recent discussions I found date back to late 2023. Additionally, the proposed solutions primarily involve workarounds that may not be reliable in the long term.
Is there an official solution to ensure that PyLance properly recognizes the tensorflow.keras namespace? I can't imagine lazy loading in general will break VSCode intellisense (although it is certainly possible I am wrong). Alternatively, are there any robust workarounds that are less likely to break in future updates? Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Software:
MacOS Sonoma 14.1.2
Python 3.12
tensorflow 2.16.1
References to previous questions/issues being posted:

https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/3249
VSCode Autocomplete And Suggestion (IntelliSense) Doesn't Work For Tensorflow And Keras Libraries?
https://community.deeplearning.ai/t/unable-to-import-tensorflow-keras-pylinte0401-import-error-in-visual-studio-code/512586
https://jagaimox.wordpress.com/2020/12/28/configure-python-intellisense-on-vscode-for-tensorflow-1-14-or-1-15/ (tensorflow 1.14/1.15)

I tried a couple of solutions in the above links and they didn't work for me. It is possible some of them require some additional configuration that I would need to do which I didn't (for instance, one referenced _typing in tensorflow.init but no _typing was already defined - could be outdated).

In the case of Python 3.12/tensorflow 2.16.1, the code added to tensorflow/__init__.py in this question needs to be changed to
if _typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
 from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.api._v2 import estimator as estimator
 from keras._tf_keras import keras
 from keras._tf_keras.keras import losses
 from keras._tf_keras.keras import metrics
 from keras._tf_keras.keras import optimizers
 from keras._tf_keras.keras import initializers



That seemed to work! Although, this does look to confirm my suspicion that these "workaround" fixes are rather temporary and likely to break in the future. Do you know of any plans for tensorflow/PyLance to fix this in the future? I could only find sporadic questions about this online and nothing indicating plans to remedy it.

@TannerHess It doesn't look like there are any plans to fix this at the moment, you can ask questions and vote on it on github. And, if you think this answer solve your issue, you could mark it as an answer. It will also help others to solve a similar issue.

A simple workaround is to create a symbolic link of Keras package to the TensorFlow package directory.
Run this command: ln -s ../keras/_tf_keras/keras/ keras
at the site-packages/tensorflow or dict-packages/tensorflow directory.
You may find the installed tensorflow package directory at

venv: .venv/lib/python3.*/site-packages/tensorflow
docker (linux): /usr/local/lib/python3.*/dist-packages/tensorflow
homebrew (macOS): /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.*/site-packages/tensorflow

